# RSpec throws false positives for elements on a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

I am having some real issues trying to figure out what is going on with my application at the moment. I am trying to ensure that I can show users different content on an 'edit profile' page depending on the method they used to sign up (OAuth or not).

I have gotten this to work correctly when manually testing in the browser by just adding an OAuth attribute to my user model and testing for that.

However, in RSpec I am unable to test this correctly. In fact no matter what elements I tell it to look for on the page it will claim that they are infact there.

```
describe "edit user" do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { sign_in user }

  describe "correct edit account options shown to normal users" do
    before do
      visit edit_user_registration_path(:user) 
    end

    it { should have_selector('h2',      text: 'Edit User') }
    it { should have_selector('input',   id:   'user_names')}
    it { should have_selector('input',   id:   'user_email', value: user.email) }
    it { should have_selector('input',   id:   'user_password') }
    it { should have_selector('input',   id:   'user_password_confirmation') }
    it { should have_selector('input',   id:   'user_current_password') }
    it { should have_selector('input',   type: 'submit') }
  end

  describe "correct edit account options shown to oauth users" do

    before do 
      user.update_attributes!(:oauth => true)
      visit edit_user_registration_path(:user)
    end

    it { should have_selector('h2',          text: 'Edit User') }
    it { should have_selector('input',       id:   'user_names')}
    it { should_not have_selector('input',   id:   'user_email') }
    it { should_not have_selector('input',   id:   'users_password') }
    it { should_not have_selector('input',   id:   'users_password_confirmation') }
    it { should_not have_selector('input',   id:   'user_current_password') }
    it { should have_selector('input',       type: 'submit') }
  end
end
```

Full Code for my RSpec Integration test is here: https://gist.github.com/2556055

Any help for this would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Excuse me, do I understand correctly that have_selector reports that you have any elements on the page, even if they really don't there?

Comment: The path helper functions should be called with `user`, not `:user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucky enough to have had a hand in solving this from the guys at #rubyonrails

The reason is that have_selector doesn't take multiple arguments (Hence why it made no difference what the IDs were). As a result they should be replaced with the have_css method instead.

So the correct implementation would be:

```
describe "edit user" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { sign_in user }

describe "correct edit account options shown to normal users" do
 before do
    visit edit_user_registration_path(:user) 
 end
 it { should have_selector('h2',      text: 'Edit User') }
 it { should have_css('input#user_name')}
 it { should have_css('input#user_email') }
 it { should have_css('input#user_password') }
 it { should have_css('input#user_password_confirmation') }
 it { should have_css('input#user_current_password') }
 it { should have_selector('input',   type: 'submit') }
end

describe "correct edit account options shown to oauth users" do

before do 
  user.update_attributes!(:oauth => true)
  visit edit_user_registration_path(:user)

end

  it { should have_selector('h2', text: 'Edit User') }
  it { should have_css('input#user_name')}
  it { should_not have_css('input#user_email') }
  it { should_not have_css('input#users_password') }
  it { should_not have_css('input#users_password_confirmation') }
  it { should_not have_css('input#user_current_password') }
  it { should have_selector('input', type: 'submit') }
 end
 end
```

Comment: Wait, you said have_selector doesn't take multiple arguments, yet you still have have_selector('input', type: 'submit') where you are using a second argument to specify the type attribute.